# VC++ error when using a pointer to a template function

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to write a template callback function for libcurl. However, when using a pointer to an instance of the template function, VC++ 2008 and 2010 keep giving me this error:

> template-callback.cpp(27) : error
>   C2664: 'curl_easy_setopt' : cannot
>   convert parameter 3 from 'size_t
>   (__cdecl *)(void *,size_t,size_t,void
>   *)' to '...'
>           Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function

But GCC (4.5.1) compiles the code without a problem. This is a trimmed version of the code:

```
#include <string>

template<typename String>
size_t callback(
    void*       ptr
  , size_t  size
  , size_t  nmemb
  , void*       userdata
)
{
  //String* str = static_cast<String*>(userdata);
  size_t    len = size*nmemb;
  //str->append(static_cast<char const*>(ptr), len);
  return len;
}

typedef size_t (*write_callback)(void*, size_t, size_t, void*);
struct CURL;
enum CURLOption { none };
void curl_easy_setopt(CURL*, CURLOption, ...);

void f()
{
  CURL* curl = NULL;
  CURLOption option = none;

  // This gives an error
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, option, &callback<std::string>);

  // This doesn't
  write_callback cb = &callback<std::string>;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, option, cb);
}
```

Is this a bug in VC++ or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Pablo: is this the exact signature of `curl_easy_setopt` ? I am wondering if the issue does not come from the variadic argument.

Comment: @Matthieu: The problem does indeed come from the variadic argument.

Comment: @Xeo: do you have any idea why, gcc-4.3.4 rejects the code too, but gcc-4.5.1 accepts it in C++0x mode. I don't use variadic arguments in general so I am a bit at a loss as to the origin of the issue :/

Comment: @Matthieu: Sorry, no clue. :/

Comment: @Matthieu M. It is almost the exact signature, except trimmed down to make it compile without dependencies.

Comment: @Pablo: then (as per my answer) it seems the issue is that the compiler is unable to correctly assess the type of `&callback<std::string>` when there is no variable to initialize (here, an ellipsis gives no hint). The work around is to specify the type, either using a temporary storage or a cast.

Comment: @Matthieu M. Indeed, adding the cast silenced the compiler on the code I posted. For some reason, though, I can't get my full code to work even after adding the cast. I'll post a follow up as soon as I can figure out the minimum code that produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue on [ideone](http://ideone.com/tharo) (C++03 with gcc-4.3.4):

```
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*FuncType)(int);

void foo(FuncType);
void bar(...);

template <typename T>
void callback(T t) { std::cout << t << "\n"; }

int main() {
  foo(&callback<int>); // OK
  bar(static_cast<FuncType>(&callback<int>)); // OK
  bar(&callback<int>); // error: address of overloaded function
                       // with no contextual type information
}
```

The issue seems to come from the interaction of the variadic argument and the function pointer.

*Note: in C++0x mode with gcc-4.5.1 [it works fine](http://ideone.com/GREYW)*

I surmise that the issue comes from the overload resolution of `bar` (or `curl_easy_setopt` in your case).

The problem is that in order to use the ellipsis, the compiler as to decide how to pass the argument: `int`, `double`, `pointer`, ... It seems that it is unable to decide, by itself, what the type of `&callback<int>` is.

When we use `foo`, or perform a cast, it is unambiguous because there is no choice.

I suspect a conversion issue, but I don't have a version of the C++03 standard to dig into.

Comment: Clang is the only compiler that accepts `bool b = &callback<int>;` correctly, from what I can see :)

Comment: @Johannes: ah! great that you're here! Could you explain exactly what's going on ?

Comment: @Matthieu It shall accept that according to the FDIS specs, like v4.5 does. See http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7505 and http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9208 . IIRC there may be an issue in C++03 that didn't allow this (i.e identifying the correct function lvalue solely based on template arguments, without a correct target type context). Please see the referred-to PRs.

Comment: @Johannes what are the FDIS specs? Googling doesn't help

Comment: @Pablo: FDIS stands for Final Draft ISO Standard. It's the last refinement of the drafts before the C++ ISO Standard is actually published (after the FDIS gets vetted by all National ISO bodies). It used to be available for download, but they seem to have removed it.